# Django ManyToMany Relation with django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class BM(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length = 255)
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

When I try to run the test with `python manage.py test` I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist`

This is due to trying to create the relation to the User table before the table gets created itself.

How can I do this?

Edited to say:

This is happening because the `BM` model table is being created before the auth User table, so the following statement is run (according to `./manage sqlall p`:

```
CREATE TABLE "p_baby_relations" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "baby_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("baby_id", "user_id")
)
;
```

The error is because of `NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user"` which means that the auth user table has not been created.

Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=not keepdb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

Comment: did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: try run manage.py makemigrations 'app_name' of this class BM

Comment: I'm running a test suite

Comment: Please show the whole stacktrace. I have a guess. Somewhere during import-time your code tries to fetch a value from the auth_user table. And this line gets executed before the testsuite creates the database tables.

Comment: No, that's not what's happening.

Comment: @guettli see my edit, it is failing when creating the DB

Comment: You could use a migration (manage.py makemigrations) and put a dependency in the migration. But I guess it is something different, since I have never done this and I have referenced the auth_user tables very often in models. Please show the stacktrace leading to the  django.db.utils.ProgrammingError.

Comment: are you using django-guardian ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify auth.User as a dependency in the migration.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('user', '0001_initial'),
    ]
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it does not work at the first try.  I have this `    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('p', '0001_initial'),
        ('user', '0001_initial'),
    ]`
for the migrations and get the error: `django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration p.0002_baby_relations dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'user', u'0001_initial')`  I think this is on the right track, though, I just need to figure out the correct idiom.

Answer (score -1):

This error says your database does not have the table `auth_user`

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist

Databasetables in django are create with `manage.py syncdb`

Comment: I'm running a test suite.